# to prove XY-plane a convex set??

Tags: convex-analysis

we know that R and R^2 have convex subsets because any two points in them can be joined by a line segment..but how we will prove it mathematically that XY-plane is a convex set??

Comment: From the definition of convexity? Take arbitrary $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: let x1=(1,0,0) and x2=(0,1,0). then by definition(1-alpha)x1+alpha x2 =x.now taking alpha=1/2 we get  (1-1/2)(1,0,0)+1/2 (0,1,0)=(1/2,1/2,0) belongs to XY-plane...so XY-plane is a convex set.is this solution correct??

Comment: the example is correct, but this is not a proof for "the XY-plane is convex".

Comment: i want its prove .can u help me plz??

Comment: Do you intuitively understand why the XY-plane is convex?

Comment: is there anybody to help me right now??

Comment: yes because every two points in it can be joined by a line segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment, i think we talk about $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
Therefore the XY-Plane is represented by the set of vectors $\left\{(x,y,0)^{T}|\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$.
A set is convex, if for any vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ the linesegment between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is in the set, too.
So the XY-plane is convex, if for all $\vec{a},\vec{b}\in\left\{(x,y,0)^{T}|\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ the following holds:

- $\lambda\vec{a}+(1-\lambda)\vec{b}\in\left\{(x,y,0)^{T}|\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\},\;\;0\leq\lambda\leq1$

Let $\vec{a}=(x_{1},y_{1},0)^T$ and $\vec{b}=(x_{2},y_{2},0)^T$ be arbitrary vectors of the XY plane. Then

$\lambda\vec{a}+(1-\lambda)\vec{b}=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda)x_{2}\\
\lambda y_{1}+(1-\lambda)y_{2}\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)\in\left\{(x,y,0)^{T}|\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

because the $x$-component and the $y$-component are in $\mathbb{R}$ and the last component is $0$.

Comment: if we want to talk about in R2 then we will not take the third copmonent and then prove it as above...is it so??

Comment: If we talk about $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then the XY-plane is the whole $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and then the convexity is trivial. But yes, the proof works for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in the same way without the third coordinate..